# JS - How to disable spacebar scrolling ONLY, but allow other spacebar functionality?

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have a website which has regular spacebar functionality, not just inside an input box, so I can't make it return false if the target is the body. I just want to stop it from scrolling down the page, but allow the other functionality. Is it possible to do this using vanilla JS? Here is my code:

```js
//Many other functions here
function spacebar() {
  window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if ((watch.isOn) && (!done)) {//u can stop it with any key
      watch.freeze();//stop the stopwatch
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 32) {
      if (done) {
        watch.start();//start the stopwatch
        stage = 1;
      }
      if (stage === 0) {
        stage = 1;
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h1 id="timer">0:00.000</h1>
    <script src="js/timer.js"></script>
    <!--The JS starts and stops this timer.-->
  </body>
</html>
```

So it starts the timer when the spacebar is pressed, and stops it when any key is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A default behaviour of pressing the spacebar is to scroll. We have the ability to prevent default behaviors using

`event.preventDefault();`

You are using window.onkeydown, passing the event argument as var e. You know how to recognize keys by keycode, as you have demonstrated. Now then, if the key that is pressed is the spacebar, then prevent the default behaviors (in this case that includes scrolling). You have the option to define your own behavior instead.

Comment: This is more suited to a comment as it doesn't provide a complete answer to the OP's question. Consider updating it with details of how this will solve the issue.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "overload the spacebar key press event"? Also putting your code inside backticks (``) is better. Can you also explain where I put this code?

Comment: Your code includes onkeydown event handling. I am assuming you know how it works and didn't just copy and paste that from somewhere. Apply e.preventDefault() if e.keyCode is the spacebar key code.

Comment: Oh, ok. So I just need to do this if the spacebar is pressed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is that You can add `e.preventDefault();` with your functionality like as i can play and pause the song but restrict the Scrolling.

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
if (e.which == 32) {
    const isMusicPaused = wrapper.classList.contains("paused");
    isMusicPaused ? pausedMusic() : playMusic();
    e.preventDefault();
}});
```